# How to get list of email addresses from Contacts for autocomplete field in Android?

Tags: android, autocomplete, cursor, contacts

I've read through the docs and searched on here, but I'm not quite understanding how all the pieces fit together. Was wondering if anyone has a clear explanation of how to grab a single column of data from Contacts and have it populate an autocomplete box.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628702/android-autocomplete-with-contacts), duplicate post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreate():

1. Created a SimpleCursor to create a managed query into the contacts database:

   Cursor emailAddressCursor = managedQuery(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, Contacts.ContactMethods.DATA + " ASC");
2. Created a SimpleCursorAdapter to connect data to the cursor.
3. Implemented setFilterQueryProvider() in my adapter to return a managed query when constraint is passed in when filtering.
4. The final step is to call setAdapter() on the TextView passing in your adapter.