# How can i show suggestions for multiple values for edittext field in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I need a functionality in android app, that is similar to Gmail app in android real device which has drop down suggestions for multiple value in "To" field or like stack overflow's tag suggestions for multiple values. For example, I entered a email address in the To field and then i need to list the email addresses for the entered text after the comma value, i I searched a lot for this functionality but i cant find the exact solution. Please advice and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the autocomplete for gmail is probably a lot more complex than you'd want. If you're interested in the source and what the actual gmail autocomplete looks like, please look at the source for [MessageCompose](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/email/activity/MessageCompose.java;h=063e63e52b2196b169227359eae4dede0e4598ba;hb=HEAD) at line `587 - 605` as well as the [GalEmailAddressAdapter](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/exchange/provider/GalEmailAddressAdapter.java;h=e0e3f4fe1b488969d5b56a31c556c2efd55c59c1;hb=HEAD) (the code that actually does the autocompletion.)

If you are doing auto completion using the user's contacts, it's a lot simpler. Please view that example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628702/android-autocomplete-with-contacts).

**Edit**: I found a much better example for you here: http://www.betaful.com/2011/02/multiple-e-mail-autocomplete-in-android/

Again, looks through contacts for autocomplete but includes code for multiple lookups.