# An autocomplete textview for contact names that get their numbers?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, textview, android-contacts

I'm trying to learn how to make an autocomplete textview in an android app would have a dropdown list of contacts with their numbers, based on the letters that the user enters that match a part of a name of a contact.

How would I accomplish this? I've spend hours on google without finding a complete solution, which I thought was odd.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

A beginner android developer

MORE DETAILS:
I wish to have a textbox similar to the recipient box for the default messaging app, where I would be able to start typing the name of a contact, and suggestions of contact names with their numbers would appear, which I would be able to click and fill my textbox with the number of that contact that I clicked.

Comment: I have found my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400504/selecting-contact-from-autocomplete-textview?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this one:

Modify how you want to display the UI

// I just hard coded the number retrive the number and append.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

String[] arrcontact = null;
AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    loadContact();

    myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
    myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrcontact));
}

private void loadContact() {
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    arrcontact = new String[30];

    int count = 0;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));


        arrcontact[count] = displayName + "\n" + "908228282";
        count++;
        if (count == 30)
            break;

    }
}

private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { "1" };
    final Cursor contacts = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, "UPPER("
                    + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    return contacts;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Hi could this solve what you need?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete

As long as you have your contact lists in a StringArray, it would allow you to use this API.

====================================

According to your added comment, it looks like you also need what this post did in **grabContacts()** with **ContentResolver** and **query**, and then creating an StringArray from the Cursor as presented in the post:

[Android - Autocomplete with contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628702/android-autocomplete-with-contacts)

(**kedark**'s solution is good and complete, though this particular method could be a bit more easy to understand for beginners)

```
private Cursor grabContacts(){
    // Form an array specifying which columns to return. 
    String[] projection = new String[] {People._ID, People.NAME};

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri contacts =  People.CONTENT_URI;

    // Make the query. 
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(contacts, projection, null, null, People.NAME + " ASC"); // Put the results in ascending order by name
    startManagingCursor(managedCursor);
    return managedCursor;
}
```

You can upvote them if this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. I wish to have a textbox similar to the recipient box for the default messaging app, where I would be able to start typing the name of a contact, and suggestions of contact names with their numbers would appear, which I would be able to click and fill my textbox with the number of that contact that I clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Kedark's loadContact() routine to work for any length contact list (below) otherwise it works well.  Thanks!

```
    private String[] loadContactList() {
        String[] contactArray;
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();

        contactArray = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        int count = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contactArray[count] = displayName;
            count++;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return(contactArray);
    }
```